# So patent application 20130025039 has been issued a PATENT?

Tags: post-grant-review, us20130025039

Has patent application 20130025039  Been granted a patent?

Answer (score 2):

No, it has not. Its status, available on public PAIR, is:

> Status:    Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination

It has not been searched or examined yet.

The USPTO has a web accessible system call PAIR (patent application information retrieval). Via [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) one can look up the status of a published patent application. If it is from mid 2003 or later, it possible to see all of the documents in the file including the back-and-forth between the applicant and the examiner. There is also a continuity tab. This will show parent and child applications that, themselves, may have resulted in issued patents.

PAIR is not very user-friendly. Do not have commas in the number. If you search by publication number be sure to set radio button to that option.

Comment: Could you flesh out this answer a bit to explain *how* to find this information for folks who may have this question about *other* patents? That way we have the canonical answer to all questions *"has {X} been issued a patent?"*

Comment: what does it really mean when you get "Entity Status:  Undiscounted "

Comment: The applicant is not claiming to be a small entity (they get 50% off their fees) and is paying full price.